# Hybrid mobile app displaying notification in mobile app

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, mobile, hybrid

I am developing a hybrid mobile app.  I want to display notification in my application top right corner.  I am using html + angularjs - front end and for backend I am using spring rest web service.

I am using cordova to just convert my frontend to native code.

Suggest me how to implement notification functionality in my frontend & backend

Note: I cannot use cordova for development.  Because I cannot install it in all developers system. Only one dedicated system available with cordova installed.  I can only use it for converting my html page to native

Answer (score 0):

can you try this for notification alert [link](https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications/)